# Unable to sort data in a `v-for` (data is not iterable) in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component

I have this component that I want to produce country data for COVID cases, but have the data sort by the cases and not the countries which it currently is.

I have tried to sort the `TotalConfirmed` data like below:

```
<template>
    <div class="container mx-auto mb-12 px-4">
        <table class="table-fixed rounded-lg shadow overflow-hidden">
            <thead class="bg-white">
                <tr>
                    <th class="w-1/3 px-4 py-2">Country Name</th>
                    <th class="w-1/3 px-4 py-2">Confirmed</th>
                    <th class="w-1/3 px-4 py-2">Deaths</th>
                    <th class="w-1/3 px-4 py-2">Recovered</th>
                    <th class="w-full px-4 py-2">Updated</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="bg-white">
                <tr v-for="(ci, i) in totalCases" :key="i">
                    <td class="border px-4 py-2">
                        {{ ci.Country }}
                    </td>
                    <td class="border px-4 py-2 text-center">
                        {{ ci.TotalConfirmed }}
                    </td>
                    <td class="border px-4 py-2 text-center">
                        {{ ci.TotalDeaths }}
                    </td>
                    <td class="border px-4 py-2 text-center">
                        {{ ci.TotalRecovered }}
                    </td>
                    <td class="border px-4 py-2 text-center">
                        {{ ci.Date | formatDate }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                data: null,
            };
        },
        computed: {
            totalCases: function() {
                const sorted = [...this.data];
                sorted.sort((a, b) => b.TotalConfirmed - a.TotalConfirmed);
                return sorted;
            },
        },
        mounted() {
            axios
                .get('https://api.covid19api.com/summary')
                .then((response) => (this.data = response.data.Countries));
        },
    };
</script>
```

This is the API I am using...

```
{
    "Global": {
        "NewConfirmed": 285196,
        "TotalConfirmed": 19096415,
        "NewDeaths": 6516,
        "TotalDeaths": 714924,
        "NewRecovered": 189126,
        "TotalRecovered": 11544750
    },
    "Countries": [
        {
            "Country": "Afghanistan",
            "CountryCode": "AF",
            "Slug": "afghanistan",
            "NewConfirmed": 67,
            "TotalConfirmed": 36896,
            "NewDeaths": 4,
            "TotalDeaths": 1298,
            "NewRecovered": 98,
            "TotalRecovered": 25840,
            "Date": "2020-08-07T19:49:47Z",
            "Premium": {}
        },
```

But now the table isn't even showing. Not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: you probably have an error on your console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initializing the `data` array with null value which is non-iterable when you come to use it with spread operator `const sorted = [...this.data];`, so you must initialize it with an empty array :

```
 data() {
    return {
      data: [],
    };
  },
```

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      data: [],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    totalCases: function() {
      const sorted = [...this.data];
      sorted.sort((a, b) => b.TotalConfirmed - a.TotalConfirmed);
      return sorted;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get('https://api.covid19api.com/summary')
      .then((response) => (this.data = response.data.Countries));
  },



})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div class="container mx-auto mb-12 px-4">
        <table class="table-fixed rounded-lg shadow overflow-hidden">
            <thead class="bg-white">
                <tr>
                    <th class="w-1/3 px-4 py-2">Country Name</th>
                    <th class="w-1/3 px-4 py-2">Confirmed</th>
                    <th class="w-1/3 px-4 py-2">Deaths</th>
                    <th class="w-1/3 px-4 py-2">Recovered</th>
                    <th class="w-full px-4 py-2">Updated</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="bg-white">
                <tr v-for="(ci, i) in totalCases" :key="i">
                    <td class="border px-4 py-2">
                        {{ ci.Country }}
                    </td>
                    <td class="border px-4 py-2 text-center">
                        {{ ci.TotalConfirmed }}
                    </td>
                    <td class="border px-4 py-2 text-center">
                        {{ ci.TotalDeaths }}
                    </td>
                    <td class="border px-4 py-2 text-center">
                        {{ ci.TotalRecovered }}
                    </td>
                    <td class="border px-4 py-2 text-center">
                        {{ ci.Date | formatDate }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```